# Formatting a value into thousands and millions

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following value coming back from a web service - 3.3178070599E10

```
var value = 3.3178070599E10;
console.log(value) // result : 33178070599

//Outputting via Ext JS number formatting utility function :
Ext.util.Format.number(Math.abs(value), '0,000') // result : 33,178,070,599
```

I need to format this value into a thousands and millions format like so

```
Thousands - 33,178,070
Millions  - 33,178
```

I have been reading up on the toLocaleString method and it's various properties but seem to be getting different values when  adding in some optional properties like maximumSignificantDigits and minimumIntegerDigits.

Are the 2 required formats specified above possible to achieve with this method or are there any other recommended approaches ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use your previous method but instead of Math.abs(value) you could do Math.floor(value / 1000) for thousands and Math.floor(value / 1000000) for millions

```js
console.log((Math.floor(3.3178070599E10 / 1000)).toLocaleString())
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was over thinking the whole approach it seems :-)

Comment: @grimmus tends to happen :)